# Is there a difference in OWL between using inverseOf and propertyChainAxiom ([inverseOf <property>])?

Tags: owl, semantic-web, reasoning

Take the following statements as an example:

```
@base           <http://ex.org/> .
@prefix owl:    <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .

<hasPart> a owl:ObjectProperty .
<compatibleWith> a owl:ObjectProperty .

<main> owl:differentFrom <part> .

<main> <hasPart> <part> .
```

I can reason that `<part>` is `compatibleWith` `<main>` by adding one of these two statements

```
<compatibleWith> owl:propertyChainAxiom( [owl:inverseOf <hasPart>] ) .
```

or

```
<compatibleWith> owl:inverseOf <hasPart> .
```

In my opinion do these two statements differ semantically for a human, as compatibility is not really an inverse of having a part.
The first would rather state if there is a hasPart relationship there is also a compatibleWith relationship in the other direction.

However, I wonder if for a OWL reasoner these two statements are basically equivalent, beside adding the blank node and propertyChainAxiom statment.
**Are there additional thinks I could (and maybe do not want to) reason with one statement but not the other?**

Answer (score 0):

The difference becomes clear when for example:

```
<compatibleWith> a owl:SymmetricProperty .
```

is added.

Using

```
<compatibleWith> a owl:SymmetricProperty .
<compatibleWith> owl:inverseOf <hasPart> .
```

also reasons the inverse here:

`<part> <hasPart> <main> .`

Following up with `<hasPart> a owl:InverseFunctionalProperty` might even lead to errors if certain parts are different.

---

```
<compatibleWith> a owl:SymmetricProperty .
<compatibleWith> owl:propertyChainAxiom( [owl:inverseOf <hasPart>] ) .
```

Does NOT reason that `<part> <hasPart> <main> .` making a crucial difference here.